# Not able to Verify Signature of the data field in json payload using RSA256 in C#

Tags: c#, json, rsa

Needto verify the signature of below JSON payload using RSA256 in C#

### **User Payload with Signature**

```
{
    "name": {
        "value": "Test",
        "signature": "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"
    }   
}
```

**VerifyData Code Block**

```
        {
            bool success = false;

            string nameValue = userInformation.name.value.ToString();
            string nametobeverify =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { name = nameValue });
            string key = RemoveHeaderFooterFromKey(publicKey);
            var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key); // your key here
            AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(keyBytes);
            RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter;
            RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
            rsaParameters.Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
            rsaParameters.Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {

                var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
                byte[] bytesToVerify = encoder.GetBytes(nametobeverify);

                byte[] signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(userInformation.name.signature);
                try
                {
                    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
                    SHA256Managed Hash = new SHA256Managed();
                    byte[] hashedData = Hash.ComputeHash(signedBytes);
                    success = rsa.VerifyData(bytesToVerify, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signedBytes);
                }
                catch (CryptographicException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
                }
            }
            return success;
        }
```

Here I am trying verify the signature of Name data field in User Payload but I am always getting false. Am I doing it the wrong way?

For each data field, there is a field name, value, and signature.

To verify a data field, need to create a json object of field name to value, stringify the object, then verify it against the signature using the verification_key(public key), using RS256.

> User Payload format  { name: { value: "John", signature: "xyz"}

dataToVerify = stringify({name: "John"})

isValid = RS256(dataToVerify, verification_key, "xyz")

Comment: This `39fb816366456d4b95d09f1c21fb07f057b54ce98` does not look like a signature, it looks more like hash.

Comment: it's signature only wrongly updated the value. 
"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"